# Number of different combinations while ordering pizza.

Tags: combinatorics

Say i wanna order a pizza, I order exactly 3 different types of additions on the pizza, From 10 different options (Black olives, Green Olives, Pepperoni, Cheese, Tuna, Chocolate, Bananas, Mushrooms, nuts and cookies).

I dislike matching up between: Black olives & Green olives, Tuna & Chocolate, Pepperoni & Bananas.

And i eat mushrooms only when they match up with Cheese.

How many different combinations can i order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  First count pizzas with mushrooms (and cheese)  How many?
Then ignore the mushrooms (I assume cheese is still OK)
Now you have 9 options to pick 3
You need to delete the ones with black olives and green olives (and three other pairs)-how many is that?
You are fortunate that you only want three toppings-you can't double count the exclusions